# Dropping observations in Stata based on length?

Tags: stata

I have a string variable in Stata called Cod. I want to drop the observations such that Cod has less than 16 characters. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at `help string functions` to learn basic syntax here.

`drop if length(Cod) < 16`

may be what you seek.